# Main Water Line coming into House leaking/rusted out - How to replace and with what?

Tags: plumbing, water, pex, galvanic-corrosion

We just purchased a home in Joshua Tree, CA and the main water line coming into the house after the exterior shut off valve is leaking a lot. The concrete over part of it came off and I am able to see the water line. I will break the rest of the concrete to reveal the rest. I believe it is galvanized steel pipe?

My question is what should I replace this with? Does pex work for exterior use if it is insulated and put into the ground?

Here is a picture....[image: Pipe]

Comment: You might consider contacting your local water utility to ask them what they recommend for your locale. When I went from well to city water, my town actually _gave_ me the pipe for the install. Of course, they knew they'd be collecting on a water bill from here on out, so their out of pocket was essentially zero, but you never know...

Comment: CA. demands may be different, but in FLA. the pipes are usually schedule 40 PVC. at least to the homes main shut off.

Answer (score 10):

Not PEX. Polyethlyene, PE, but not crosslinked - well water pipe is a fairly good search term. The 200PSI stuff is the most robust (thickest wall) I'd not go down to 100PSI (thinner wall, more fragile and prone to kinking.) 200 and 160 PSI are pretty tough. Unlike PVC they are not brittle.

Beware that breaking up more concrete without a replacement ready to install may mean big leak and no water in house.

No insulation needed if the iron pipe didn't need any. I doubt you get much freezing weather there, given where the pipe is.

Comment: I've got to wonder why this was down-voted,   PE is great for supply lines, no special tools needed,  no corrosion problems. earthquake resistant.

Comment: PE is what almost all food grade plastic is made out of.  Some still uses BPA/S where the S hasn't been proven yet to have endocrine disruptors (xenoestrogens).  PE is also cheaper per foot than pex and the standard fittings are compression/threaded so you don't need some crazy sized pex crimper.

Comment: PE is what I was given by my municipality 30 years ago...

Comment: Last two houses I've owned (one in WA state and one in CA) provided two separate supplies.  Potable came in flexible copper stubbed up next to the foundation and irrigation came in thick PE stubbed up in a handhole next to the curb.  Potable was metered and irrigation was not (neighborhood association common).  Possibly the material difference was because they were added at different times, but I always had to wonder why PE was always used for non-potable.

Comment: Even the place we lived in with a well was supplied with PVC, not PE.  This was in WA state as well.  Codes in both states allow PE for potable, so must have just been a pricing/availability thing.

Comment: The PE I suggest is marked for potable water use. There is cheaper irrigation-grade PE that's not.

Comment: Yes, PE for water use, what can go wrong ... microplastics, for example? https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.9b03673
Sure, better this than arsenic or lead in iron pipes, but it is still good to have some concerns about safety&health.

Comment: @EarlGrey 90° C is an atypical temperature for water pipes in the ground - your linked article is mostly smoke and mirrors with very little actual data, just vague "concerns" for "further investigation." Likewise, MDPE is primarily for gas distribution. HDPE is used for drinking water.  So MDPE antioxidants breaking down when exposed to chlorine at 90 °C is not actually relevant to drinking water distribution.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the article is infact a "scientific opinion non-peer reviewed", as posted in the abstract in the right column. The question in the title is not the usual rethorical question, but a real question. Chlorine at Ph 6.8 and 90°C degrades the HDPE on a time scale relevant ot the laboratory (seconds? minutes? hours? I don't know). What about temperature of 10°C and time scale of 5-6 orders of magnitude longer? That is the question in this scientific opinion

Comment: No, it was shown to degrade MDPE. Not HDPE. So it's speculating, a LOT.

Answer (score 8):

**TLDR:  Yes it's allowed, but with some caveats.**

Semi-local answer: (I am in Riverside county for reference).

California Plumbing Code allows the following types of pipe for building supply piping:

> **California Plumbing Code: Table 604.1 - Materials for Building Supply and Water Distribution Piping and Fittings**
>
> *...snipped to include just the column for Building Supply...*
>
> *Copper and Copper Alloys, CPVC, CPVC-AL-CPVC, Ductile Iron, Galv. Steel, Malleable Iron, PE, PE-AL-PE, *PEX*, PEX-AL-PEX, PP, PVC, Stainless Steel*

PEX is allowed for building supply, but with the following notes:

> 2. When PEX tubing is placed in soil and is used in potable water systems intended to supply drinking water to fixtures or appliances, the tubing or piping shall be sleeved with a material approved for potable water use in soil or other material that is impermeable to solvents or petroleum products.
> 3. PEX tubing shall meet or exceed the requirements of ASTM F876-2013a or an equivalent or more stringent standard when used in continuously recirculating hot water systems and the PEX tubing is exposed to the hot water 100% of the time.

So, yes you can use PEX in the ground, but you'd have to sleeve it inside another approved potable water pipe to bury it.   Note 3 doesn't apply since this is supply, not hot water distribution.

Reading that, it seems that using PEX would be a waste of effort and pipe, seeing as you'd have to essentially double your piping.  I'd use Copper or PVC if it were me - they are both easy to cut and fit, rated for pressure, rated for potable water, and available in most of the stores around this area.

FWIW, my house is supplied by flex copper from the utility to the meter, then PVC from the meter to the house (house built in 2010).

Answer (score 1):

There exist some good answers to the question of the best pipe replacement. Make sure you also check codes for electrical grounding applicable to your installation. A solid conductive pipe provides good earthing for your homes water supply. In the case that the electrical grounds are defective or deteriorated, replacing metal pipe with non-conductive polymer pipe may lead to a dangerous situation.

At the least, when you cut the pipe, first have the cut bridged with a copper jumper, and measure any current flowing with a clamp meter. Then, with an AC voltmeter across the cut, remove the jumper temporarily. More than a couple of volts, or any current flowing indicates a potentially dangerous situation with your electrical supply, which should be urgently rectified.